# HTML web scraping for a value

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i made a python program with beautifulsoup that is supposed to find a certain value from a site but, the program doesn't seem to find the value.

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as ureq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url = 'http://www.calcalist.co.il/stocks/home/0,7340,L-4135-22212222,00.html?quote=%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%A8'
uclient = ureq(my_url)
page_html = uclient.read()
uclient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
value = page_soup.find("td",{"class":"RightBlack"})
print(value)
```

the value i am trying to find is the dollar converted into Israeli currency but for some reason the line of code the is supposed to retrieve that value:

```
value = page_soup.find("td",{"class":"RightBlack"})
```

can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1. First Option, what you can do using BeautifulSoup

Notice the element you want to get is inside an `iframe`, which means this is another request, different from the one you made, you can do a code to iterate over all `iframes` and print the price if it finds a `iframe_soup.find("td",{"class":"RightBlack"})`.

I'd recommend to use the `except` statement, since it's easy to fall into url traps when doing this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as ureq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'http://www.calcalist.co.il/stocks/home/0,7340,L-4135-22212222,00.html?quote=%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%A8'
uclient = ureq(my_url)
page_html = uclient.read()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

iframesList = page_soup.find_all('iframe')
i = 1
for iframe in iframesList:
    print(i, ' out of ', len(iframesList), '...')
    try:
        uclient = ureq("http://www.calcalist.co.il"+iframe.attrs['src'])
        iframe_soup = soup(uclient.read(), "html.parser")
        price = iframe_soup.find("td",{"class":"RightBlack"})
        if price:
            print(price)
            break
    except:
        print("something went wrong")
    i+=1
```

Running the code, this outputs:

```
1  out of  8 ...
2  out of  8 ...
3  out of  8 ...
4  out of  8 ...
5  out of  8 ...
<td class="RightBlack">3.5630</td>
```

So now we have what we want:

```
>>> price
<td class="RightBlack">3.5630</td>
>>> price.text
'3.5630'
```

---

## 2. Second Option, use [`Selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

This is a recommendation, to do requests and JavaScript handling you should use **[`Selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)** with a JS interpreter, below I'm using **[`ChromeDriver`](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)**, but you can also use **[`PhantomJS`](http://phantomjs.org/download.html)** for a headless browsing. Inspecting the frame element, we know it's id is `"StockQuoteIFrame"` to get there, we use `.switch_to_frame`, and then we can easily find our `price`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.calcalist.co.il/stocks/home/0,7340,L-4135-22212222,00.html?quote=%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%A8'

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)

browser.switch_to_frame(browser.find_element_by_id("StockQuoteIFrame"))
price = browser.find_element_by_class_name("RightBlack").text
```

The output, of course, is the same as the first option:

```
>>> price
'3.5630'
```